Prometheus Metric disappears after amount of time (~5 Minutes)
We have a Prometheus Server up and Running to monitor some of our Applications and Services. One of the Services that we monitor is an oracledb_exporter. Currently we scrape that Exporter every 10 Minutes.
This is the corresponding prometheus.yml:
global:
  scrape_interval: 30s
  evaluation_interval: 30s

rule_files:
  - rules.yml

alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9093']
      scheme: http

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'Oracle-DB'
    scrape_interval: 10m
    scrape_timeout: 1m
    scheme: http
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9161']
        labels:
          instance: 'DB'

But if i check for example the up Metric i can see that the Entry for Up disappears every ~5 Minute.

This is the corresponding rule.yml:
groups:
- name: General
  rules:
  - alert: Running
    expr: up == 0
    for: 5m
    annotations:
      summary: "Instance {{ $labels.job }} - {{ $labels.instance }} down."
      description: "{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been down for more than 5 minutes."

This also leads to not beeing informed when the service is down.

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness

10 minutes normally is too long for a scrape interval.
